# App get crashed when make a call using Plivo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, plivo

I am trying to integrate my android app with Plivo. I've tried sample project from github (https://github.com/plivo/plivo-android-examples) and that works fine. I am using plivo outbound and tried PlivoOutbound as well as PlivoDialler project. Outbound call was successful.

But the problem is coming when I am trying to integrate the lib into my existing project. It was succeed to login, but got crashed when trying to make a call. Here's the error logs:

```
A/libc: ../src/pjsip/sip_endpoint.c:241: pjsip_endpt_unregister_module: assertion "pj_list_find_node(&endpt->module_list, mod) == mod" failed
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 17004 (Thread-4743)
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 16977 (xample.outbound)..
```

I think the error is related to native libs on libplivo.so, But I don't know why that error isn't happened on another project that use same library.

Any solution?